# Can not open USDZ file with QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using Quicklook to preview files. There was a issue previously in iOS10.x, showing this Service Connection Interrupted error while repeatedly opening the same file. And this was supposed to be fixed in iOS11. Now in iOS12, I am getting the same error message.

> [default] QLItemViewController (contents:
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/Library/Documents/RetroTV.usdz)
>   did fail with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain
>   Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}. #PreviewCollection

Is there any workaround or fix for this issue or Apple has to fix it again in future release? Anyone else facing this issue in iOS12.x? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Usually this means that ASVAssetViewer process crashed. This is the reason why connection was lost. You can try to check crashlog on device for ASVAssetViewer crashes.